# Please explain me Callback function like I'm a 5 years old

Tags: javascript, callback

I've just written this code:

```
function doOperation(val1, val2, operation){
    
    operation(val1, val2);
    
    }
    
function sum (a, b){
    
    console.log(a+b);
    
    }
    
    doOperation(2,4,sum);
```

As you can see in this code, I'm using a callback function **(sum)** However, the parameter of the function (operation(**val1, val2**)) inside main function and callback function **(sum)** are completely different and that's what confuses me.

Once again, the operation function taking these two named parameters: "val1" and "val2"

However, when we pass the callback function, we're passing "a" and "b" as a parameter.

If the callback function is replacing what function inside the main function, shouldn't the parameter value be the same?

Can anyone explain how its possible to have different parameter names or I'm missing something?!

Comment: The third param `operation` is a reference to a function you pass to it. It's just an alias.

Comment: This isn't really related to a callback function at all. The name of the variable you're passing as a parameter **does not** have to be the same as the name of the parameter (indeed when you call `doOperation`, the values `2` and `4` aren't assigned to names at all; you don't have to do `const val1 = 2, val2 = 4;` beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> doOperation(2,4,sum);
> ```

You call `doOperation` with three arguments. The third one happens to be a function.

> ```
> function doOperation(val1, val2, operation){
> ```

The value of the third argument to `doOperation` is assigned to the variable named `operation`.

> ```
> operation(val1, val2);
> ```

`operation` is called as a function (which is fine, the value passed in is a function).

Two arguments are passed to it. `val1` and `val2` those are the first two arguments passed to `doOperation`.

> ```
> function sum (a, b){
> ```

The function expects two arguments, they get assigned to the variables `a` and `b`.

…and so on.

---

> If the callback function is replacing what function inside the main function

The callback function isn't *replacing* anything.

> Can anyone explain how its possible to have different parameter names

When you *call* a function, you put a series of expressions between `(` and `)`.

> ```
> doOperation(2,4,sum);
> ```

In the above case those are two number literals and a variable that contains a function.

The **values** are passed to the variables defined in the function definition:

> ```
> function doOperation(val1, val2, operation){
> ```

So `2` goes to `val1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The `operation` callback is just a function that you pass to the `doOperation` function. The `doOperation` function takes two values and hands them off to the `operation` function.

An better example of what's happening would be to show how multiple callback `operation` functions can be called.

```js
const doOperation = (v1, v2, fn) => fn(v1, v2); // or fn.call(null, v1, v2)
    
const operations = {
  sum        : (a, b) => a + b,
  difference : (a, b) => a - b,
  product    : (a, b) => a * b,
  quotient   : (a, b) => a / b
};

const x = 2, y = 4;

// Direct reference to operations
console.log(doOperation(x, y, operations.sum));        // 6
console.log(doOperation(x, y, operations.difference)); // -2
console.log(doOperation(x, y, operations.product));    // 8
console.log(doOperation(x, y, operations.quotient));   // 0.5

// Dynamic reference to operations
for (const operation in operations) {
  console.log(doOperation(x, y, operations[operation]));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Reducers and sorters heavily rely on the types of callbacks shown above.

```js
const values = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
    
const operations = {
  sum        : (a, b) => a + b,
  difference : (a, b) => a - b,
  product    : (a, b) => a * b,
  quotient   : (a, b) => a / b
};

console.log(values.reduce(operations.sum, 0));        // 6
console.log(values.reduce(operations.difference, 0)); // -6
console.log(values.reduce(operations.product, 1));    // 6
console.log(values.reduce(operations.quotient, 1));   // 0.167
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```